# programmatically focus jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I'm trying to focus the input of a jQuery UI autocomplete when my page loads.
The following code picks up the correct input field, but the .focus() call does not focus the control:

```
$("#autocomplete").next().find('input');
```

Additional info:
MVC 4 app using EF4.5, jQquery 1.10.2 & jQuery UI 1.10.3

Comment: try creating a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried creating a jsfiddle example, but for some reason the jquiery ui autocomplete does not work in jsfiddle